# php notification templating using xml or anything

Tags: php, mysql, xml, codeigniter

Sorry if my question is a little confusing, i have made a **Notification system** using php with codeigniter framework which is working all good. i am using helper to create notifications and check for new notifications. In my case there is only one notification as of now ie.. payment remainder which checks for due date and adds notification to db.

What i am trying to do is to create a form where admin-user will be able to create notifications without the need of programming a helper everytime.

please let me know what is the best way to apporach this situation.

Regards
Max

Comment: Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.